# slowly change hex color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, colors

I want a function that takes as input a hex color, and slowly change color, and then, in a loop, the output as input to do it. like the color picker, which will slowly change color with scroll-bars

for example reach rgb(232, 23, 23) from rgb(111, 232, 23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think RainbowVis-JS is what you are looking for:

```js
$(function() {
  var cur = 0;
  
  var rainbow = new Rainbow(); 
  rainbow.setNumberRange(0, 1000); // number of colors in the gradient
  rainbow.setSpectrum('999999', 'd40d12');
  
  setInterval(function() {    
    var color = rainbow.colourAt(cur);
    
    console.log(color);
    $('#color').css('background', '#' + color);
    
    cur++;
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
#color {  
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS/master/rainbowvis.js"></script>

<div id="color"></div>
```

https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS